# Apache POI - what is impact of 'The maximum number of Cell Styles was exceeded. You can define up to 64000 style in a .xlsx Workbook'

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI  (https://poi.apache.org/) and I notice the following message when I create an excel spreadsheet :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The maximum number of Cell Styles was exceeded. You can define up to 64000 style in a .xlsx Workbook
```

This is appearing at warning level and the excel spreadsheet generated seems correct. What is the impact on Excel generation when this exception is thrown?

Referring to this question [java.lang.IllegalStateException: The maximum number of Cell Styles was exceeded. You can define up to 64000 style in a .xlsx Workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66801718/java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-maximum-number-of-cell-styles-was-exceeded) suggests the spreadsheet is not created when this exception is thrown, but I have not observed this behavior.

Comment: The linked question doesn't suggest that the spreadsheet isn't created (it doesn't suggest that it **is** created either, but one could assume that it's just missing some styling information).

Comment: you should reuse the styles on many cells - excel applies the limit and POI just obeys - it makes little sense to create 64000 styles

Comment: Maybe the spreadsheet can be created and even can be opened by Excel. But cell styles which exceed the count limit will not be applied. That looks like this question then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116172/apache-poi-sometime-renders-localdatetime-as-double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the client opening the generated file, it might be impossible to open the file or impossible to save changes to the opened file.

To prevent this you should create cell styles only once, maintain a reference to the style, and apply the same style to multiple cells, which should have the same style. Instead of creating multiple styles with the same configuration for multiple cells. There is no duplication detection in place that would prevent you from creating multiple styles with the same configuration or reusing them in the background.